# Getting GitHub PHP project to work

Tags: php, composer-php, router

I want to explore and learn from the project [here](https://github.com/laracasts/The-PHP-Practitioner-Full-Source-Code) that has a video series on Laracasts. However I have run into a few problems.

I cloned the repo from GitHub and ran `composer install` then visited the folder's index.php in Chrome.

The first error was from line 67 of core/Router about Exception not existing. So I added a backslash (`\Exception`) and that seemed to fix that problem. But now I'm getting `Uncaught Exception: No route defined for this URI. in C:\Program Files (x86)\Ampps\www\dev\The-PHP-Practitioner-Full-Source-Code\core\Router.php on line 67`

At this point I'm out of my depth since I'm trying to use the project to learn about composer, autoloading, namespacing etc.

I tried adding a .htaccess file without really knowing what I was doing, but that made no difference.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Could someone please try and install the project and tell me what's needed to make it work?

Comment: What does your htaccess look like and what URI are you trying when you get that exception? And where have you set your document root for the web server?

Comment: URL was `http://localhost/dev/The-PHP-Practitioner-Full-Source-Code/` .htaccess added in edit above. The document root is shown in the error message above.

Comment: The error message just shows what file the exception occurred in. It doesn't tell us what folder the web servers document root is set to. But your URL doesn't have any matching route (when looking in the repo). The registered routes are: `/`, `/about`, `/contact`, `/users` while the URL you're trying to access is: `/dev/The-PHP-Practitioner-Full-Source-Code`. You need to set the web servers document root to the folder where you're .htaccess-file is, or prepend all routes with `/dev/The-PHP-Practitioner-Full-Source-Code`